# Doxygenating literal strings from a static array?

Tags: doxygen

I'm new to Doxygen and am trying to figure out if it can be used for the following need.

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct definition {
  int val;
  const char* name;
  const char* desc;
} DEFINITION;

static const DEFINITION def[] =
{
  {1, "abc", "def"},
  {3, "ghi", "jkl"},
  {5, "mno", "pqr"}
};
```

Is it possible to produce an HTML table out of the strings in that array? If so, can you give me a hint about where to look in the Doxygen manual for how to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar with the `/snippet` command; it basically quotes the actual code so you don't have to repeat any documentation, and it **always** matches the code.

```
   typedef struct definition {
     int val;
     const char* name;
     const char* desc;
   } DEFINITION;

   /**
   * This constant has been initialized as:
   * \snippet thisfile.c def_definition_marker
   */
   static const DEFINITION def[] =
   {
   //![def_definition_marker]
     {1, "abc", "def"},
     {3, "ghi", "jkl"},
     {5, "mno", "pqr"}
   //![def_definition_marker]
   };
```

See: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsnippet